# Java Swing Repaint Latency

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I have a simple paint program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class CanvasPanel extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener
{
    private int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    public CanvasPanel()
    {
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setBounds(50,50,400,250);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        new CanvasPanel();
    }

    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        paint(g);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
    {
        mouseEvent.consume();
        int x = mouseEvent.getX();
        int y = mouseEvent.getY();

        if ( x1 == 0 )
        {
            x1 = x;
        }

        if ( y1 == 0 )
        {
            y1 = y;
        }

        x2 = x;
        y2 = y;
        repaint();
        x1 = x2;
        y1 = y2;
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me)
    {

    }
}
```

If you run it, you will see that there is a lag when painting with your mouse and the drawing will disintegrate into dots the faster you go. How do I fix this? I was thinking if the repaint is super fast, then the dots should form into lines and curves.

Comment: First, don't override `paint` on a top level container like `JFrame`, use a `Panel` instead and override its `paintComponent` method instead. Understand the painting is considered destructive, this means that you are expected to completely repaint the component state from scratch each time paint is called, bad things will happen if you don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few things to learn when painting.  I have done a fair amount of graphics so I modified your program to illustrate.

1. Don't extend `JFrame` unless you plan to override something.  It is seldom necessary.
2. Do your painting in a `JPanel` that overrides `paintComponent()`.
3. Collect your points in an `array` or `list` to run thru them each time.  This is because the call to `super.paintComponent()` will clear the screen (but it is necessary to do so).
4. Not required but I find it convenient to use `MouseAdapter` (or any *-Adapter) in a private class to handle events.
5. Since Swing is not thread safe it is a good idea to start it in the EDT.  Just make certain that no long processing is done while in the `EDT` or your program will lock up and become unresponsive.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CanvasPanel extends JPanel {
   List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
   // Use compositon over inheritance.
   // Don't extend JFrame unless you plan to override something.
   JFrame      frame  = new JFrame();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new CanvasPanel());
   }
   public CanvasPanel() {
      MyMouseListener ml = new MyMouseListener();
      addMouseMotionListener(ml);
      addMouseListener(ml);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
      frame.add(this);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center on screen
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      if (points.size() >= 2) {
         Iterator<Point> it = points.iterator();
         Point p1 = it.next();
         while (it.hasNext()) {
            Point p2 = it.next();
            g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
            p1 = p2;
         }
      }
   }

   // MouseAdapter provides dummy implementations
   private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
         points.add(me.getPoint());
         repaint();

      }
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
         // initialize first point in list.
         points.add(me.getPoint());
      }
   }
}
```

This example still has problems.  For example, if you release the mouse button and position to a new location and then click, it will continue from the last point.  There are probably many ways to fix this but the simplest would be to have a list of lists, where each list is a separate set of points with detached origins.

Comment: Oh wow, this is a great starting point!  Could you explain more how you fixed the dotted lines? And what was causing it?

Comment: You had the right idea.  Draw a line from the the first point to the next and then make the next point the first and repeat the process.  You just didn't update them correctly.  Since you didn't do super.paint() it didn't clear the line so you didn't need the list of points.  But with painting you need to preserve everything and have it all repainted each time paint is called.  What i did was initialize the `list` in the mousePressed method.  Then successive points were obtained during the dragging process.

Comment: The following tutorial link covers a variety of topics including painting.  It was last updated to include Java 8 so it is rather dated. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html